# How can I create itunes/finder/mail style table view

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview, nscell, nstableviewcell

I'd like to create the content lists in the style of the Finder window's left pane (similarly in the style Mail/iTunes/etc). Currently my `NSTableView`/`NSOutlineView` implementation looks a little basic.

Is there any tutorial that can help me mimic the Apple look? In particular, I'm after the header rows, the colours, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standard, documented, development pattern to create UI layouts similar to iTunes, iCal, iPhoto, etc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934036/is-there-a-standard-documented-development-pattern-to-create-ui-layouts-simila)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a source list first: `setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList`

You can get those really cool headers by implementing a delegate method: 
    `- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView isGroupRow:(NSInteger)row` or the NSOutlineView counterpart: 
    `- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item`.

```
[myOutlineView setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList];
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item {
    return [self itemIsGroupItem:item];
}
```

This would get you the selection gradient, blue background, etched header rows, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [PXSourceList](https://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList), it has the Apple look & feel.